How can I delete an Azure SQL firewall rule using az cli?
I am trying to delete a rule in firewall settings for an Azure SQL, but I get an error.
I am using the following command:
az sql server firewall delete --firewall-rule-name $ruleName --server-name $serverName -g    $resourceGroupName > $null

but it doesnt delete the rule and says "--firewall-rule-name is misspelt".
How can I delete a rule using az cli ? I want to delete all rules in one go

You can use the following process to delete all firewall rules using Azure CLI in Azure SQL Server.
List the firewall rules using the code below:
az sql server firewall-rule list -s <serverName> -g <resourceGroupName> --query "[].{Name:name, StartIpAddress:startIpAddress, EndIpAddress:endIpAddress}" --output table


How can I delete a rule using AZ CLI? I want to delete all rules in one go.

You can use the following code to delete all firewall rules in one go:
for rule in $(az sql server firewall-rule list -s <serverName> -g <resourceGroupName> --query "[].name" --output tsv); do
    az sql server firewall-rule delete --name $rule --server <serverName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName>
done

This will delete all firewall rules, as shown below:

Update

would this delete all rules on all severs in a subscription ? Also where do you make sure that you dont delete " AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" which is the check box for "Allow Azure services and resource to access this server"

It will delete all rules in the specified SQL server. If you want to delete all firewall rules in all servers in a subscription, first list the servers and use a for loop to define the server name as mentioned as the firewall rule. You can use the code below to delete all firewall rules except AllowAllWindowsAzureIps:
for rule in $(az sql server firewall-rule list -s <serverName> -g <resourceGroupName> --query "[?name!='AllowAllWindowsAzureIps'].name" --output tsv); do
    az sql server firewall-rule delete --name $rule --server <serverName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName>
done

This process deletes all firewall rules except AllowAllWindowsAzureIps, as shown below:


would this delete all rules on all severs in a subscription ? Also where do you make sure that you dont delete  " AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" which is the check box for "Allow Azure services and resource to access this server"

also is that syntax using the done , az cli for powershell ?

I updated my answer according to your requirement and I run above commands in azure cli.
